# Animation Display Block to Display None - CSS

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

Display None to Display Block animation is working
but I need the animation to work this way also 
- Animation Display Block to  Display None

the animations is not working when action go from block to Display None

have an idea what can be the problem?

```
#dboldDiv,#dbnewDiv {
 animation: anim .4s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transitions on the CSS display property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property)

Comment: You can't. There is not intermediate step between `none` and `block`

Answer (score 2):

**display is not animatable property**

---

There are two category of properties **animatable** and **not animatable**

you can check animated properties list from here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Answer (score 0):

`display:none` won't work smooth.
For fluent disappearing try using `visibility:hidden`, or if just keep 0 opacity and add `pointer-events:none`, so the object doesn't catch any mouse events.

```js
document.getElementById('hide').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('link').className = 'hide';
});

document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('link').className = 'show';
});

document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert('clicked');
});
```

```css
#link {
  display:block;
}
#link.show {
  animation: anim1 .4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#link.hide {
  animation: anim2 .4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
    pointer-events:none;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events:all;
  }
}
@keyframes anim2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.3;
    pointer-events:none;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events:all;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<a href="#" id="link">hidding &amp; showing</a>
```

Comment: I have on click event onclick="newDivHere()"  where I use the display - can you show a code example - what you mean, I just don't think that the  visibility:hidden will work

Comment: @IvanDern Here you go :) You can't click, until `pointer-events:all` is active, even `cursor:pointer` doesn't work.

Comment: i used your code in my case is nothing different  - the animation from  Display Block to Display None when I click is not working

Comment: @IvanDern Ok, I've updated the answer - now you can see, that in 'hidden mode' there are no events working on link, even though it has `href` and the `click` `eventListener`. The animation works both ways fine.

Comment: @IvanDern You don't seem to use complex animation, I'd suggest to use transition instead.